# Estimate P(X > 2E[X]/X > E[X])

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Suppose $X \sim $ exp($\lambda$). Is it possible to find $P(X > 2E[X]/X > E[X])$ for any $\lambda$ in general? If possible, how should I proceed?

If not, how can I estimate the same probability value with a fixed $\lambda$?

I tried coding this problem and obtained different probability values for different $\lambda$ values. So, now I am interested in estimating the value mathematically using CDF or PDF.

Comment: exponential law has no memory.

Comment: @Surb Do you mean P(X > 2E[X]/X > E[X]) = P(X > 2E(X)/X)?  But I didn't get the same answer using simulation. Can you please explain?

Comment: no, that $\mathbb P\{X>2\mathbb E[X]\mid X>\mathbb E[X]\}=\mathbb P\{X>\mathbb E[X]\}$.

Comment: @Surb But my question is not conditional probability

Comment: Then, what's the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda), \\ f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, \quad x > 0,$$ then $$\operatorname{E}[X] = 1/\lambda$$ and $$\Pr\left[ X > \frac{2\operatorname{E}[X]}{X} > \operatorname{E}[X]\right] = \Pr\left[X > \frac{2}{\lambda X} > \frac{1}{\lambda} \right].$$  This compound inequality is equivalent to $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\lambda}} < X < 2,$$ hence $$\Pr[(2/\lambda)^{1/2} < X < 2] = \begin{cases} e^{-\sqrt{2\lambda}} - e^{-2\lambda}, & \lambda > 1/2, \\ 0, & 0 < \lambda \le 1/2. \end{cases}.$$